# Painter example in SICP

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket, sicp, pict

The "Painter" example from SICP 2.2.4 is pretty interesting, and gives ways to create nice Escher-like paintings. For example, a recursive right-split procedure can be done something like:

```
(define (right-split painter n)
  (if (= n 0)
      painter
      (let ((smaller (right-split painter (- n 1))))
         (beside painter (below smaller smaller)))))
```

However, none of these examples can actually be run or visualized. Is there any sort of "input painter" that can be used (even ASCI text/art, like a circle or square) to illustrate how the procedures can actually be used in a complete manner?

Answer (score 1):

[Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/SICP_Picture_Language.html) can help with this:

```
#lang sicp

(#%require sicp-pict)

(define (right-split painter n)
  (if (= n 0)
      painter
      (let ((smaller (right-split painter (- n 1))))
         (beside painter (below smaller smaller)))))

(paint (right-split einstein 2))
```

[image]

Comment: If you run into problems using `sicp-pict` with the sicp language, then use `#lang racket` and then `(require sicp-pict)` for that chapter.